# EWS Partial sync soap request returns organizer name as appointment subject

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am currently working on a project where the system, which is a node.js web server subscribes to push notification for changes in the resource calendars of an Exchange server. We followed the MSDN documentation to subscribe and communicate with the Exchange server using SOAP requests.

We used SOAP request below to fetch the changes and store them in the local database of the web server.  The '+roomCalId' and '+syncState+' values are replaced with room calendar Id and its corresponding sync state which are stored previously in the database when subscribing.

```
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"></t:RequestServerVersion>
        <t:TimeZoneContext>
            <t:TimeZoneDefinition Name="UTC" Id="UTC"></t:TimeZoneDefinition>
        </t:TimeZoneContext>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>+roomCalId+</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:SyncFolderItems>
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:SyncFolderId>
                <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar" />
            </m:SyncFolderId>  
            <m:SyncState>+syncState+</m:SyncState>  
            <m:MaxChangesReturned>500</m:MaxChangesReturned>
            <m:SyncScope>NormalItems</m:SyncScope>
         </m:SyncFolderItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The process worked perfectly without any problems for the first few calendars. However, for newly created room calendars, the soap request above returns the organizer's name as appointment title instead of the actual title. Is there a reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats is a default setting on Room mailboxes where the Organiser name is used to replace the Subject of a Meeting. This is done for security reasons as most people have access to Meeting rooms but generally people like HR might not want people to see the subject of the meeting (eg meeting to talk about downsizing etc). You can change this setting using the Set-CalendarProcessing cmdlet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046(v=exchg.160).aspx and the AddOrganizerToSubject parameter